# ReferenceError: loadJSON is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, atom-editor

I am using **Atom**, and I have **node.js** installed and **npm install -g json**
Everything went okay with the installation and the version prompted on the cmd window. I'm running a server through **nodemon server.js**

```
 //server.js

  var words = loadJSON('words.json');

  //words.json

  {
   "rainbow": 5,
   "cat dog": 6
  }
```

How come I keep getting this reference error? I also have the **p5** library that has the **loadJSON** method so I am not sure where else can go wrong.

Comment: p5 won't run on node server side as it is dependent on accessing the window object. Have provided you with another way of reading the file below. Let me know if this solved your issue

Comment: Is this browser/client code or node/server code?

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of NodeJS can import a JSON file directly:

```
const words = require('./words.json');
```